# std::process::Command cannot run hdiutil on macOS (mount failed - No such file or directory) but the command works fine when run in the terminal

Tags: macos, process, rust

`hdiutils`, when fed a correct path to a valid file, returns `error 2, no such file or directory`. When I join the indices of the command array with `" "`, print them, copy them and run the exact string in a terminal, it works fine.

This is the function edited to contain only the relevant bits. In order to reproduce my error, you will need a disk image located at `~/Downloads/StarUML.dmg`.

```
use std::env;
use std::fs;
use std::process::Command;

fn setup_downloads(download_name: &str) {
    let downloads_path: String = {
        if cfg!(unix) {
            //these both yield options to unwrap
            let path = env::home_dir().unwrap();
            let mut downloads_path = path.to_str().unwrap().to_owned();
            downloads_path += "/Downloads/";
            downloads_path
        } else {
            "we currently only support Mac OS".to_string()
        }
    };

    let files_in_downloads =
        fs::read_dir(&downloads_path).expect("the read_dir that sets files_in_downloads broke");
    let mut file_path: String = "None".to_string();
    for file_name in files_in_downloads {
        let file_name: String = file_name
            .expect("the pre string result which sets file_name has broken")
            .file_name()
            .into_string()
            .expect("the post string result which sets file_name has broken")
            .to_owned();

        if file_name.contains(&download_name) {
            file_path = format!("'{}{}'", &downloads_path, &file_name);
        }
    }

    let len = file_path.len();

    if file_path[len - 4..len - 1] == "dmg".to_string() {
        let mount_command = ["hdiutil", "mount"];
        let output = Command::new(&mount_command[0])
            .arg(&mount_command[1])
            .arg(&file_path)
            .output()
            .expect("failed to execute mount cmd");

        if output.status.success() {
            println!(
                "command successful, returns: {}",
                String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stderr).into_owned()
            );
        } else {
            println!(
                "command failed, returns: {}",
                String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stderr).into_owned()
            );
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    setup_downloads(&"StarUML".to_string());
}
```

[image: if evaluates true when the correct file is detected in downloads]

[image: error response from process::Command]

Comment: I want to state that I am not highschool educated let alone a CS student, so I am very likely missing alot of important parts that I have not been able to acquire just by working the tools until I have a functional project. I am trying to spread the passion for automation to others in similar situations, so I would appreciate any pointers to improve the code quality from the viewpoint of someone who is missing alot of CS context.

Comment: I certainly hope that you won't find anyone here on Stack Overflow that treats you different due to a difference in formal education. We are equally strict on programmers of all backgrounds ;-).

Comment: the condition file_path[len - 4..len - 1] == "dmg".to_string() only evalulates to true if you have the StarUML installation dmg in your ~/Downloads directory on a mac. you can find the dmg at http://staruml.io/download, that should help that condition pass and let you see the error I get

Comment: so far you guys have been extra helpful and I appreciate the fact that you guys have responded without prejudice (I never felt that you had at any time so far). I really want this code to build for you guys, so make sure you get the dmg mentioned in my comment above.

Comment: Please don't include error messages as images. These are not accessible and cannot be indexed by search engines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split your `Command` into a variable and print it using the debugging formatter after you have specified the arguments:

```
let mut c = Command::new(&mount_command[0]);

c
    .arg(&mount_command[1])
    .arg(&file_path);

    println!("{:?}", c);
```

This outputs

```
"hdiutil" "mount" "\'/Users/shep/Downloads/StarUML.dmg\'"
```

Note that `Command` automatically provides quoting for each argument, but you have added your own set of single quotes:

```
format!("'{}{}'", &downloads_path, &file_name);
//       ^    ^
```

Remove these single quotes.

Comment: thanks dude, that works for this example, I had added them because I was having trouble on the windows platform and Command was not adding them after the fact so the windows command interpreter was only using getting the string up to the unescaped space char. I will finish putting together the mac bits and try it again in windows, and if the behaviour is still the same, I will use a condition to set up the windows only filePATH with quotes.